# asp.menu control moving To Left on maximizing window

Tags: asp.net, .net

Hi i have a menu control in my master page.

When I maximize the browser Window the menu Alone is moving To the left of screen. on mouse over the menu Is getting aligned properly and vice verse when shrinking the window

```
 <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="background-color: Black; height: 30px; ">
            <tr style="background-color: Black; height: 30px;">
                <td  style="background-color: Black; width: 100%; height: 30px;">
                <div style="height:30px">
                    <asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" EnableViewState="false"             RenderingMode="Default" CssClass="menu" ForeColor="White"
                        IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal" Height="30px" OnMenuItemClick="NavigationMenu_MenuItemClick" >
                        <StaticMenuItemStyle CssClass="menuitem" />
                        <DynamicMenuItemStyle CssClass="menuitem" />
                        <Items>
                            <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Home.aspx" Text="Home" ToolTip="Home page" />
                            <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/CommonUser.aspx" Text="Create / Edit User Access" ToolTip="Provide access to users" />
                            <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/BulkUpload.aspx" Text="Bulk Upload" ToolTip="To bulk upload users " />
                            <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/SearchUser.aspx" Text="View / Revoke User Access" ToolTip="View existing users access" />

                            <asp:MenuItem Text="Admin" NavigateUrl="javascript:void(0);">
                                <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="javascript:void(0);" Text="User" ToolTip="Create / Edit User for the application">
                                    <asp:MenuItem Text="Create User" NavigateUrl="~/AdminUser.aspx" />
                                    <asp:MenuItem Text="Edit User" NavigateUrl="~/EditAdminUser.aspx" />
                                </asp:MenuItem>
                                <asp:MenuItem Text="Template" NavigateUrl="javascript:void(0);">
                                    <asp:MenuItem Text="Create Template" />
                                    <asp:MenuItem Text="Edit Template" />
                                </asp:MenuItem>
                                <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="javascript:void(0);" Text="Server" ToolTip="Add / Edit server Details">
                                    <asp:MenuItem Text="Add Server" NavigateUrl="~/AddServers.aspx" />
                                    <asp:MenuItem Text="Edit Server" NavigateUrl="~/EditServer.aspx" />
                                </asp:MenuItem>
                                <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/CreateConString.aspx" Text="Environment Password" ToolTip="Change password for connection string" />
                            </asp:MenuItem>

                        </Items>
                    </asp:Menu>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

the CSS fro THe same is as below

```
div.menu
{
    padding: 2px 1px 4px 8px;
} 


.PrimaryNav
{
    position: relative;
    height: 30px;
    background: black url left top repeat-x;
}

div.menu ul
{
    list-style: none;
    margin:0;
    padding: 0px;
    width: auto;
   /* background-color:#A9A9A9;*/
}

div.menu ul li a, div.menu ul li a:visited
{
   border-left: 1px White solid; 
   background:black;
   /* border-right: 2px White solid; */
   text-align:left;
   font-family: Segoe UI, Verdana, Tahoma, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;   
    color: White;
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight:normal;
    line-height: 1.35em;
    padding: 4px 20px;
    text-decoration: none ;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: auto;


}
```

The code is developed in .Net4.0
The issue occurs in IE 6 and IE 7 . I didn't check this in later version as most of the machines are having IE 7 here.

PLease help me resolving the issue

Comment: Add proper CSS. padding setting required

Comment: What should the menu be doing when the window is maximised? The menu is currently styled to be 100% of the screen width and will therefore stretch to fit it. If you need it to be centralised and a fixed width, set the outer table's style to 'style="width:800px; margin:0 auto;"' and remove 'width="100%"'

Comment: I have placed this control in form tag. the form has a fixed length. once the Page is maximized. the control is going outside the form tag

Answer (score 0):

in general, i've found that playing with display:block on various parts of an asp:menu control has solved some issues for me. 
i also see some relative positioning. does it need a width? is something going to be absolutely positioned?